# Не выполняется mysql запрос.

Tags: запрос, php, mysql

```
function test() {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks`");
 mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `tasks` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

 while(...) {
  ...
 }
}
```

Почему-то не срабатывает этот запрос:

> > mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `tasks` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

Comment: Может вам надо вывести записи, отсортированные в обратном? Тогда сортировку просто в запросе делайте:

    SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY `id` DESC

Comment: @Modal , уточните что именно Вам нужно получить от запроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@ModaL](/users/6646/modal)](/users/6646/modal) так **что** нужно сделать?

1. *ALTER TABLE* - инструкция "изменить таблицу". Подробнее см. [ALTER TABLE](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/alter-table.html)
2. *ORDER BY* - инструкция "сортировать по"

Answer (score 2):

В случае, если вы хотите сделать вывод таблицы с сортировкой, то используйте SELECT вместо ALTER

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

а если вам нужна новая таблица с тем же содержанием, но с постоянной новой сортировкой по умолчанию, то

```
CREATE TABLE `new_tasks` SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

а если хотите поменять сортировку по умолчанию в существующей:

```
ALTER TABLE  `new_tasks` ORDER BY  `id` DESC
```